# What CronTrigger State will prevent a call to System.abortJob to fail?

Tags: trigger, scheduled-job, scheduled, cron

Looking at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_crontrigger.htm and I see that it has state values such as:

The current state of the job. The job state is managed by the system. Possible values are:

```
WAITING—The job is waiting for execution.
ACQUIRED—The job has been picked up by the system and is about to execute.
EXECUTING—The job is executing.
COMPLETE—The trigger has fired and is not scheduled to fire again.
ERROR—The trigger definition has an error.
DELETED—The job has been deleted.
PAUSED—A job can have this state during patch and major releases. After the release has finished, the job state is automatically set to WAITING or another state.
BLOCKED—Execution of a second instance of the job is attempted while one instance is running. This state lasts until the first job instance is completed.
PAUSED_BLOCKED—A job has this state due to a release occurring. When the release has finished and no other instance of the job is running, the job’s status is set to another state.
```

What CronTrigger status will prevent system.abort to fail on a job ID? (Besides the ID being invalid or null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the only statuses that should cause AsyncException to be thrown are as follows:

- COMPLETE
- ERROR
- DELETED

You can't abort something that is already finished, has errored (which also implies finished), or deleted.

I know for certain that I've aborted WAITING, ACQUIRED, and EXECUTING jobs. I can't really verify PAUSED, BLOCKED, or PAUSED_BLOCKED, but presumably, since they are not completed, they should be abortable.

Unfortunately, the documentation does not come right out and tell us, the above information I have is only through observations I've seen historically.

Comment: that answer is an awesome one. I too looked at the sparse documentation and was running to the same conclusion in the testing that I have been doing.

Comment: It's worth noting that you also explicitly require the "Modify All Data" permission to abort jobs using `System.abortJob` - something that isn't usually granted to standard users.